# Mongoose - Date tomorrow and the day after

Tags: mongoose

Is there a way in `mongoose` to get the `Date` for tomorrow and the day after? I know the date for today can be obtained using `Date.now`.

Comment: Are you using default date value as `Date.now` (or the tommorow's date), or you want to save tommorow's date in the DB, using `save`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I consider that your problem have nothing related to mongoose. MongoDB is WHERE you store the data, and it's independant from the data itself.

I assume that your real hided question is how to get the date of tomorrow or the day after.

To manipulate Dates I recommand to use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) package.

```
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').toDate();
const tomorrowPlusOneDay = moment().add(2, 'day').toDate();
```

[Here is moment documentation about Node.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!